# В каком пакете в nuget находится @inject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Использую asp.net framework, для отображения авторизованного пользователя хочу сделать как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891589/how-do-you-display-a-users-full-name-in-the-login-partial-view-in-asp-net-core), чтобы можно было передавать дополнительную инфу о пользователе. Но при запуске пишет, что @inject не работает:

> CS0103: The name 'inject' does not exist in the current context

Как я понял, нужно добавить asp.net Core. Какую именно добавить надо?
Установил:

1. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
2. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
3. Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
4. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
5. Microsoft.AspNetCore

Comment: Это наверное в каком-нибудь пакете Razor - но видите ли какая штука... В настоящее время принято [ставить метапакет](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1)  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App и не париться. Это удобно.

Comment: @A K, При добавлении пишет не может найти: .netframework version=v4.6.1 were not found. Хотя целевая платформа указана 4.6.1 в настройках проекта. Не подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Нет, слишком мало данных. Покажите свой csproj хотя бы. Все типовые шаблоны проектов вам видимо не подошли и вы идёте какими-то совершенно нехоженными тропами. Чем вам например не угодил типовой проект asp.net core empty app?

Comment: @AK, Так как на данном проекте, мне кажется проще решить данную проблему, а не делать все по новому.